# FFMPEG Video merge command: How to influence resulting quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having a hard time understanding the following ffmpeg command :

```
'-y -i MY_VIDEO_1 -i MY_VIDEO_" -r 24000/1001 -filter_complex \'[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out]\' -map \'[out]\' OUTPUT_PATH;
```

I use it to merge two videos to one but the resulting video has a worse quality than I would expect but can't really figure out how to influence the resulting quality.

I would like to know what exactly influences the quality of the resulting video and what I need to change for better quality

Comment: it is going to use whatever the defaults are for the container if you don't specify a `-c:v` with some params

Comment: Your command is obfuscated by variables, and you didn't provide the complete log, so we are unable to tell what encoder you are using. Therefore no specific answer can be provided.